# Do the same column names in different tables in mysql DB could make an error while importing to power bi?

Tags: mysql, powerbi, connection, ssh-tunnel

do power Bi will accept the columns with the same but in different tables? I am trying to import my mysql DB to powerbi and I got error "An entry with the same key already exists error". The only topic that I found on internet said that means that there is 2 columns with the same name. [An-entry-with-the-same-key-already-exists-error](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Power-Query/An-entry-with-the-same-key-already-exists-error/td-p/2991)

Comment: *do power Bi will accept the columns with the same but in different tables?* No problems when the tables are imported or accessed separately. But when the tables are joined then each column name must be accompanied with source table alias, and each output column must be aliased uniquely.

Comment: So I cannot import my DB with just one connection. Any table will need to be done separately?

Comment: As per my knowledge, this is not an issue until you used the column in any DAX or calculations. For that, you need to add Table Name before the Column name to avoid ambiguity.